# How to update attribute of one model from the controller of second model

Tags: ruby-on-rails

In my rails application, there is a model named Message and other is Organization. In the message controller the data is inserted in the table messages, one of the attribute that is saved is no_of_message that is being counted in the create action itself. In the organizations table there are two fields promo_limit and trans_limit. 
If sms_type is "TRANS" I want to subtract the value of trans_limit field from no_of_message and update it.
Similarly if sms_type is "PROMO", than the value of promo_limit has to be subtracted and updated.
Following are the parameter received by message_params

```
 Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"QHUDS5jfZNvPb4bnASyxjWgKwFaLF0/LSYUY+qHH/109e0xlLsxSsGUluCjVCeLBrK6ga6np64mHRlQ9sLSBbA==", "message"=>{"message_text"=>"sample message", "sms_type"=>"PROMO", "sendto"=>"Teaching", "sent_to"=>"34434343243, 7869851872", "organization_id"=>"4"}, "contact_nos"=>["34434343243, 7869851872"], "contact_no"=>["34434343243", "7869851872"]}
```

Following is the create action

```
def create
    @message = Message.new(message_params)
    @message.no_of_message = @message.sent_to.try(:split,",").try(:count)
    @message.sent_to = message_params[:staff_type]

    respond_to do |format|
      if @message.save
        format.html { redirect_to @message, notice: 'Message was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @message }
      else
        format.html { render :new }
        format.json { render json: @message.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end
```

Comment: Is there a relationship between organization and messages?  i.e Organization has_many messages or some kind of hatbm relationship?

Comment: @mb2nd yeah there is relationship, Organization has_many messages

Comment: Doesn't look like your create attaches the message to an organization.  You can get whatever org you want by doing Organization.find_by_some_field_name("some param")(if your using active record).  Attach that org to the message by saying @message.organization = org before saving message.  Do all necessary logic to the org  and save it also.

Comment: @mb2nd, I am new to rails, I am not getting what you are trying to explain

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rails models

```
Class Message
  belongs_to :organization

Class Organization
  has_many :messages
```

Assuming your message table has an organization_id in the DB.  Rails associations will allow you to create/update and retrieve relational object.  If your messages belong to an organization, when you create a new message you would need to assign it to an organization.  Before you can assign it an organization you would either need to know the id of the organization you want to attach the message to or you could retrieve the organization object by any field that is defined on the object.  So if you had a unique field called name on your organization you could say

```
org =Organization.find_by_name("foo") 
@message.organization = org
if @message.save
  if params['sms_type'] == "TRANS"
    org.trans_limit = @message.no_of_message - org.trans_limit
  elsif params['sms_type'] == "BAR"
    #same thing for other business logic
  end
  org.save
end
```

The point is you have to get the organization object base on the business logic for your use case and then you can manipulate it and save it.

Here is a link to the rails association guide 
http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html

Comment: I will try this one and will get back with the results.

Comment: I am getting an error at the following line
@message.organization = org
The error is undefined method `organization=' for #<Message:0x007f7d08a07eb8>

Comment: I commented the line @message.organization = org
And now it is working. Thank for your answer